# How to attach values of an array to another array in php

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays that look like this:

```
$ownerIds = [1, 2, 3];

$car = [
   ['brand' => 'Honda', 'type' => 'City'],
   ['brand' => 'Toyota', 'type' => 'Avanza'],
];
```

How can I attach each of `$ownerIds` to `$car` so it should be something like this:

```
$car = [
   ['owner_id' => '1', 'brand' => 'Honda', 'type' => 'City'],
   ['owner_id' => '2', 'brand' => 'Honda', 'type' => 'City'],
   ['owner_id' => '3', 'brand' => 'Honda', 'type' => 'City'],
   ['owner_id' => '1', 'brand' => 'Toyota', 'type' => 'Avanza'],
   ['owner_id' => '2', 'brand' => 'Toyota', 'type' => 'Avanza'],
   ['owner_id' => '3', 'brand' => 'Toyota', 'type' => 'Avanza']
];
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question. How do you know what ID belongs to what car?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will create the array of the element that you specify in your question

```
$ownerIds = [1, 2, 3];

    $car = [
        ['brand' => 'Honda', 'type' => 'City'],
        ['brand' => 'Toyota', 'type' => 'Avanza'],
    ];


    $new_arr = array();

    foreach($ownerIds as $id)
    {
        foreach($car as $c)
        {
            $c['owner_id'] = $id;

            $new_arr[] = $c;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you put the `$car` array in outer loop and `$ownerIds` in inner loop then it will give the exact result which OP asking for.